# Inserting an optional semicolon between two selected fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is my SQL clause

```
ISNULL((LTRIM(RTRIM(Masters.comment1))+';'+LTRIM(RTRIM(masters.comment2))),'')Note1 ,
```

When there are no value in both the column, then I am getting only a semicolon. If the value is not in `comment1` then I am getting `;xyz`.

I want that:

- when no value is in `comment1` and `comment2` then `note1 = ''`
- when no value in `comment1` but there is a value in `comment2` then `xyz`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will add the semicolon when there is data is both columns

```
SELECT 
  COALESCE(LTRIM(RTRIM(comment1)),'') + 
  CASE WHEN NULLIF(comment1, '') + NULLIF(comment2, '')IS NULL THEN '' ELSE ';' END +
  COALESCE(LTRIM(RTRIM(comment2)),'')
FROM yourtable
```

Comment: Did not know `NULLIF('     ', '')`  = `NULL`. Thanks!

Comment: if you compare  'ab  ' =  'ab' they are equal as well. Not when using LIKE though 'ab' like 'ab ' is false

Answer (score 4):

You can use `NULLIF` to turn empty string to `NULL`. Then concatenation of `NULL` with ';' would still be `NULL` and that can be turned into and empty string with `ISNULL`:

```
WITH masters (comment1, comment2) AS (
    SELECT NULL, NULL UNION ALL
    SELECT ' 1', NULL UNION ALL
    SELECT NULL, '2 ' UNION ALL
    SELECT '3 ', ' 4' UNION ALL
    SELECT ''  , ''   UNION ALL
    SELECT ' 5', ''   UNION ALL
    SELECT ''  , '6 ' UNION ALL
    SELECT '7 ', ' 8'
)
SELECT
    ISNULL(
        (
            ISNULL(NULLIF(LTRIM(RTRIM(masters.comment1)), '') + ';', '')
            + NULLIF(LTRIM(RTRIM(masters.comment2)), '')
        )
        , ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(masters.comment1)), '')) Note1
FROM masters;
```

*Update*: [Jorge Campos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/460557/jorge-campos) has a nice and very easy to read solution using `CASE`:

```
WITH masters (comment1, comment2) AS (
    SELECT NULL, NULL UNION ALL
    SELECT ' 1', NULL UNION ALL
    SELECT NULL, '2 ' UNION ALL
    SELECT '3 ', ' 4' UNION ALL
    SELECT ''  , ''   UNION ALL
    SELECT ' 5', ''   UNION ALL
    SELECT ''  , '6 ' UNION ALL
    SELECT '7 ', ' 8'
)
SELECT        ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(masters.comment1)), '') + 

    CASE WHEN ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(masters.comment1)), '') <> ''
          AND ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(masters.comment2)), '') <> ''
         THEN ';'
         ELSE ''
    END +  
              ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(masters.comment2)),'') AS Note1 
FROM masters;
```

Answer (score 0):

If either is null use blank space, else ';'. If either is null coalesce will return `NULL` otherwise 'eithernull'

```
LTRIM(RTRIM(Masters.comment1))
+ CASE WHEN (coalesce(@a + @b, 'eithernull')) = 'eithernull' THEN '' ELSE ';' END 
+ LTRIM(RTRIM(masters.comment2))
```

Comment: This would give `NULL` when any of `comment1`, `comment2` is `NULL` and still add ';' if `comment1` or `comment2` is empty but not `NULL`.

Comment: @Y.B. OP didn't mention either of them being empty so I didn't cover that case.

Comment: @Y.B. I had assumed OP meant NULL but  reading the question again, you might be correct that he's referring to empty strings.